# Is targeting worn magic items considered the same as targeting the wearer?

Tags: spells, dnd-3.5e, magic-items, targeting

The spellblade enhanchement says it protects from a spell targeted on the wielder of such a weapon. But what about its items?

Say, for example, I have a spellblade that protects me from dispel magic (obviously the single target version of the spell) but my enemy casts dispel magic on my gloves of dexterity. Does the spellblade protects my item from such a casting?

More in general, if some effects protects you from targeted spells (such as spell turning) does it also protect your worn items?

Comment: Out of curiosity, given [your table's history](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129308/8610) with the *spellblade*, has the DM considered just banning the magic weapon special ability as more trouble than it's worth? (My campaigns include a handful of bans for things like this that I've found to be just no fun long term.)

Comment: There isn't a single DM in our group, we kinda rotate periodically and we all follow the same rules, so we choose what to ban or how to interpet a rule (and similar things) democratically. And while I agree spellblade is one of those things that may give issues, we had worse with other stuff (like the manyfang dagger, which i also asked a question about!)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this DM uses the [grabbing an item](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#grabbing-items) and the [sundering a carried or worn object](http://dndsrd.net/specialAttacks.html#sundering-a-carried-or-worn-object) rules as they're written, this DM extends the [object saving throw](http://dndsrd.net/carryingAndExploration.html#object-saving-throws) rules to have effects that target a creature's attended objects treated as targeting the creature itself unless the effect says to do otherwise. For example, in this DM's campaigns, an [efreet](http://dndsrd.net/monstersG.html#efreeti) (that possesses the subtype [fire](http://dndsrd.net/monsterTypes.html#fire)) wearing (and therefore attending) *gloves of dexterity* renders its *gloves of dexterity* immune to fire damage.

Be aware that this house rule grew from a long discussion about whether PCs needed to acquire outfits that themselves possessed innate fire resistance so as to avoid roaming around naked on the Elemental Plane of Fire. Eventually I ruled that PCs' magical fire resistance extends to their outfits because—in addition to more serious reasons—efreeti aren't naked in their illustrations and burks still call it the City of Brass rather than thinking they're funny by dropping the *Br*. My campaigns have been better as a result of this ruling, and I've been using it for years with success.

So far as I'm aware, though, this is merely this DM's extension of the existing rules and never stated outright by the game. That makes the possibility of other tables making different rulings high. It's even possible a table never develops a general rule and decides everything case by case. This player wouldn't walk away from a campaign that ruled differently unless the DM were obviously and deliberately using the ruling to make the game less fun.

### The *spell turning* spell and the *spellblade* ability are exceptions

The 7th-level Sor/Wiz spell [***spell turning***](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#spell-turning) [abjur] (*Player's Handbook* 282-3) says that a *spell turning* effect "turns only spells that have you *as a target*" (emphasis mine). In other words, even if a creature affected by a spell turning effect is attending an object, if that object is specifically targeted by a spell the *spell turning* effect won't protect that object.

For example, a creature protected by a *spell turning* effect would still see a druid destroy that creature's [adamantine battleaxe](http://dndsrd.net/magicItemsAW.html#adamantine-battleaxe) were the druid to target it with the 4th-level Drd spell [*rusting grasp*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsPtoR.html#rusting-grasp) [trans] (*PH* 273) modified with the metamagic feat Reach Spell (*Complete Divine* 84). (The metamagic feat's necessary for the example as the *spell turning* spell "also [automatically] fails to stop touch range spells.")

The magic weapon special ability ***spellblade*** (*Player's Guide to Faerûn* 141) (6,000 gp; 0 lbs.) is far sloppier, though, than the *spell turning* spell. (Also see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/129308/8610).) The *spellblade* description says that the *spellblade*'s picked spell "must be one that is targeted against the wielder, not one that affects an area or creates an effect," yet after the spell's picked there's no limit on the *spellblade* ability's capacity to affect that spell.

This means that a DM that even allows the magic weapon special ability *spellblade* to be keyed to a spell that offers a variety of target choices, areas, or effects—like the 3rd-level Sor/Wiz spell [*dispel magic*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsDtoE.html#dispel-magic) [abjur] (*PH* 223) does—must also decide how that works… and should tell the player before the PC buys a *spellblade* keyed to such a spell.

Specifically, in this DM's campaigns, the magic weapon special ability *spellblade (dispel magic)* doesn't affect *dispel magic* spells that target anything other than the *spellblade*'s possessor. To be clear, that means in this DM's campaigns, by default, the wielder of *+1 spellblade (dispel magic) kukri* is protected from *dispel magic* spells, but the *+1 spellblade (dispel magic) kukri* remains *itself* vulnerable to *dispel magic* spells! While this ruling may *sound* like it makes the weapon special ability useless, this DM tries to keep his metagaming to a minimum, and folks that find the security the *spellblade* ability provides necessary don't usually find their *+1 spellblade (dispel magic) gauntlet* targeted by *dispel magic* spells.